# "...Ему надо было сначала приникнуть к реликвиям его веры" - можно?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> Прежде чем увидеть Папу Римского, услышать службу в храме над телом
>   апостола Петра, поучаствовать в общей молитве и получить благословение
>   наместника Бога на земле, путник проходил пешком сотни, а иногда и
>   тысячи километров. И теперь уже здесь, в самом Риме, **ему надо было
>   сначала приникнуть к реликвиям его веры**. Особо чтимыми **святынями
>   считались – ступени лестницы** дворца Понтия Пилата, по которой шёл
>   Христос и на которую капали капли его крови; столб, у которого
>   бичевали. Нужно было поклониться и сверкающему ковчегу с яслями, в
>   которые Иисус был положен при рождении...

Можно ли оставить как есть тире, авторское:

*Особо чтимыми святынями считались –*

Comment: "Его веры" вынуждает искать, к кому же отнесено второе местоимение (к путнику произвольной веры, к Богу, к наместнику, к Папе или к апостолу Петру). Поскольку это мешает чтению, лучше убрать местоимение совсем или заменить его указанием на христианскую веру. Тире тоже лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо, Сашко. Об тире автор плакать будет... В Рим!

Comment: «Особо чтимыми святынями считались – ступени...» Особо чтимыми считаются (1) мощи святых, (2) их личные вещи, а далее — храмы, лики, образа. Ступени и столб — особо памятные во дворце. ======= «...лестницы,.. по которой шёл Христос и на которую КАПАЛИ КАПЛИ его крови» — лестницы, по которой ступали окровавленные ноги Христа.

Comment: Двоеточие или тире обязательны (двоеточие, наверное, получше будет). Предупредительную паузу о перечислении необходимо обозначить. Розенталь  вот что говорит:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp1033. Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том случае, когда необходимо предупредить читателя, что дальше следует перечисление:Из-под сена ВИДНЕЛИСЬ: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Т.);

Comment: А здесь однородные члены распространенные, разделенные точкой с запятой, а это тоже увеличенная пауза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Особо чтимыми святынями считались – ступени лестницы дворца Понтия Пилата, по которой шёл Христос и на которую капали капли его крови; столб, у которого бичевали.

Если просто убрать тире, то первое восприятие будет: "считались ступени лестницы", а пока читатель доберется до столба, он забудет, где начало фразы.

Если тире заменить двоеточием, то все станет на свои места. Есть ли у автора право ставить тире — сомневаюсь.

Впрочем, есть замечание. Перечисление, состоящее всего лишь из двух элементов, воспринимается плохо. Надо бы переделать фразу. Например:

**Особо чтимыми святынями считались ступени лестницы дворца Понтия Пилата, по которой шёл Христос и на которую капали капли его крови, а также столб, у которого его бичевали.**

> ... столб, у которого бичевали.

Бичевали всех подряд? Ведь стал этот столб реликвией веры из-за того, что бичевали именно Христа!

Comment: Я сделала так: *Особо чтимыми святынями считались: ступени лестницы дворца Понтия Пилата, по которой шёл Христос и на которую капали капли его крови; столб, у которого бичевали... Нужно было поклониться и сверкающему ковчегу с яслями...* - в конце нет отточия, предложения-перечисления продолжаются. А после "бичевали" - моё. Да не всех подряд, там же тэ-зэ, народ поймёт.

Comment: По-моему, авторская оригинальность работает только во вред этому предложению, осложняет читателю жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

1) ПРИНИКНУТЬ,  1. Припасть к чему-л.

Послушные зову Церкви, мы приходим в храм Божий и здесь, пред иконой «Взыскание погибших», чувствуем, что мятущиеся наши души взысканы, найдены Матерью Божией для того, чтобы помочь нам в светлые минуты духовного прозрения отрешиться от суетных волнений, **приникнуть к Ее святой иконе,**  [Проповедь в день святого архистрата Михаила и прочих небесных сил бесплотных (1965) (2003) //

2) Тире заменяет двоеточие и обозначает последующее перечисление.

3) Согласование верное: "особо чтимыми святынями считались", так как первым стоит сущ. во мн.числе.